# Silverlight - TabControl refusing to fill remaining space

Tags: c#, silverlight

At my wits end with trying to get a TabControl and TabItems to fill a NavigationPage/Frame.
I have a MasterPage, with a Frame, that will get swapped out for different Pages, which are comprised of UserControls.

The problem I am having is that the TabControl is cutting off the UserControl and not auto sizing properly. Below is an image and the source for the Pages and Controls.

[Field below Location is cutoff] https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXz2J.jpg

MainPage.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="TournamentControls.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:navigation="clr- 
namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
xmlns:uriMapper="clr-  
namespace:System.Windows.Navigation;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="800">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Name="topNavi" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock Name="TournamentsNavi" Text="Tournaments"    
MouseLeftButtonUp="TournamentsNavi_MouseLeftButtonUp" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
        <TextBlock Name="DivisonsNavi" Text="Division"   
MouseLeftButtonUp="DivisonsNavi_MouseLeftButtonUp" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
        <TextBlock Name="EventsNavi" Text="Events" 
MouseLeftButtonUp="EventsNavi_MouseLeftButtonUp" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
        <TextBlock Name="CompetitorsNavi" Text="Competitors" 
MouseLeftButtonUp="CompetitorsNavi_MouseLeftButtonUp" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
        <TextBlock Name="MastersNavi" Text="Masters" 
MouseLeftButtonUp="MastersNavi_MouseLeftButtonUp" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
        <TextBlock Name="RefereesNavi" Text="Referees" 
MouseLeftButtonUp="RefereesNavi_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <navigation:Frame x:Name="PageContent" Background="#007A0909" Grid.Row="1"   
Navigated="PageContent_Navigated" Navigating="PageContent_Navigating">
        <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
            <uriMapper:UriMapper>
                <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" 
MappedUri="/Pages/{pageName}.xaml"/>
            </uriMapper:UriMapper>
        </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
    </navigation:Frame>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

TournamentsPage.xaml

```
    <navigation:Page x:Class="TournamentControls.Tournaments" 
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       xmlns:navigation="clr-   
namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
       xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
       xmlns:toolkit2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
       xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:TournamentControls.Controls.Tournaments"
       d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480" Title="Tournaments Page">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <toolkit2:TabControl>
        <toolkit2:TabItem x:Name="CreateTab" Header="Create Tournament">
            <cc:TournamentsCreateControl/>
        </toolkit2:TabItem>
        <toolkit2:TabItem x:Name="ModifyTab" Header="Modify Tournament">
            <cc:TournamentsModifyControl/>
        </toolkit2:TabItem>
    </toolkit2:TabControl>
    </Grid>
    </navigation:Page>
```

TournamentsCreateControl.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,4,0,4" Style="{StaticResource TaskGridMenuBarBorderStyle}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Border Style="{StaticResource TaskGridMenuBorderStyle}" Margin="0,0,25,0" Padding="10,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <StackPanel x:Name="pnlTaskGridToolbar" Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <!-- save  -->
                    <Button x:Name="SaveButton" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" 
                                 Click="SaveButton_Click" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Save BMC Structure" Margin="0,0,5,0"  >

                        <Button.Content>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="../../Resources/Icons/Save.png" Margin="0,0,2,0"  />
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">Save Tournament</TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>

                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" x:Name="LabelsSP" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,10">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="TournamentLbl" Text="Tournament Name:" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="TournamentTbx" Width="100" MaxLength="255"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="LocationSP" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="LocationLbl" Text="Location:" FontWeight="Bold"  Margin="60,0,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="LocationTbx" Width="100" MaxLength="255"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" x:Name="DateTimeSP" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="DateTimeLbl" Text="Tournament Time:" FontWeight="Bold"  Margin="3,0,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <toolkit2:DatePicker x:Name="DateTimePicker"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel x:Name="ButtonSP" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

TournamentsModifyControl.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,4,0,4" Style="{StaticResource TaskGridMenuBarBorderStyle}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Border Style="{StaticResource TaskGridMenuBorderStyle}" Margin="0,0,25,0" Padding="10,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <StackPanel x:Name="pnlTaskGridToolbar" Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <!-- save  -->
                    <Button x:Name="SaveButton" Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" 
                                 Click="SaveButton_Click" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Save Tournament Changes" Margin="0,0,5,0"  >

                        <Button.Content>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="../../Resources/Icons/Save.png" Margin="0,0,2,0"  />
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">Save Tournament Changes</TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>

                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" x:Name="TournamentsSelectSP" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,10">
                <TextBlock x:Name="CurrentTournamentsLbl" Text="Current Tournaments:" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="CurrentTournamentsCbx"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="LabelsSP" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                <TextBlock x:Name="TournamentLbl" Text="Tournament Name:" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="TournamentTbx" Width="100" MaxLength="255"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" x:Name="LocationSP" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                <TextBlock x:Name="LocationLbl" Text="Location:" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="60,0,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="LocationTbx" Width="100" MaxLength="255"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" x:Name="DateTimeSP" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                <TextBlock x:Name="DateTimeLbl" Text="Tournament Time:" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="3,0,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <toolkit2:DatePicker x:Name="DateTimePicker"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You can try out XAML Spy. You may find that one of the containers in your hierarchy is collapsing by claiming a height less than the sum of its children.

Comment: Running XAML Spy and it actually displays the silverlight controls correctly whereas no other browser can/will. Need to do some inspecting with the application, but it is weird behavior.